# Convert Dict to DataFrame in Julia

Tags: dictionary, macros, type-conversion, dataframe, julia

Suppose I have a `Dict` defined as follows:

```julia
x = Dict{AbstractString,Array{Integer,1}}("A" => [1,2,3], "B" => [4,5,6])
```

I want to convert this to a `DataFrame` object (from the `DataFrames` module). Constructing a `DataFrame` has a similar syntax to constructing a dictionary. For example, the above dictionary could be manually constructed as a data frame as follows:

```julia
DataFrame(A = [1,2,3], B = [4,5,6])
```

I haven't found a direct way to get from a dictionary to a data frame but I figured one could exploit the syntactic similarity and write a macro to do this. The following doesn't work at all but it illustrates the approach I had in mind:

```julia
macro dict_to_df(x)
    typeof(eval(x)) <: Dict || throw(ArgumentError("Expected Dict"))
    return quote
        DataFrame(
            for k in keys(eval(x))
                @eval ($k) = $(eval(x)[$k])
            end
        )
    end
end
```

I also tried writing this as a function, which does work when all dictionary values have the same length:

```julia
function dict_to_df(x::Dict)
    s = "DataFrame("
    for k in keys(x)
        v = x[k]
        if typeof(v) <: AbstractString
            v = string('"', v, '"')
        end
        s *= "$(k) = $(v),"
    end
    s = chop(s) * ")"
    return eval(parse(s))
end
```

Is there a better, faster, or more idiomatic approach to this?

Comment: another way `DataFrame(Any[collect(keys(x)), collect(values(x))])`

Comment: @GnimucKey Nice, wouldn't have thought of that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another method could be

```
DataFrame(Any[values(x)...],Symbol[map(symbol,keys(x))...])
```

It was a bit tricky to get the types in order to access the right constructor. To get a list of the constructors for `DataFrame`s I used `methods(DataFrame)`.

The `DataFrame(a=[1,2,3])` way of creating a DataFrame uses keyword arguments. To use splatting (`...`) for keyword arguments the keys need to be symbols. In the example `x` has strings, but these can be converted to symbols. In code, this is:

```
DataFrame(;[Symbol(k)=>v for (k,v) in x]...)
```

Finally, things would be cleaner if `x` had originally been with symbols. Then the code would go:

```
x = Dict{Symbol,Array{Integer,1}}(:A => [1,2,3], :B => [4,5,6])
df = DataFrame(;x...)
```